Accessing Angular Environment Variables in firebase-messaging-sw.js
I'm trying to access Angular environment variables in my firebase-messaging-sw.js file to initialize Firebase. However, I'm encountering issues with importing the environment variables directly into the service worker. I've tried to use import environment but getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Is there any to access environment variables in the firebase-messaging-sw.js instead of hard coding them??
firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    projectId: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    authDomain: '',
    apiKey: '',
    appId: ''
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

manifest.json
{
    "gcm_sender_id": ""
}

app.module.ts
//Firebase initilization
initializeApp(environment.firebase);

app.component.ts
import { environment } from '@env/environment';

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestFirebasePermission();
}

private requestFirebasePermission(): void {
        const messaging = getMessaging();

        getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: environment.firebase.vapidKey })
            .then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    console.log('Hurraaa!!! we got the token.....');
                    console.log(currentToken);
                    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
                    // ...
                } else {
                    // Show permission request UI
                    console.log(
                        'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.'
                    );
                    // ...
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                // ...
            });
    }

